# Meaning of call stack in simple program

Tags: c

I've read about the call stack, so as a test I tried to run a program that prints the call stack of the current program. But I can't understand some values. Below you can see my small test program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(unsigned long *last_out_of_stack){
    unsigned long first_out_of_stack = 0x3;
    unsigned long *i;
    int j = 1;
    printf("Line: Address          Value \n");
    for(i = &first_out_of_stack; i <= last_out_of_stack; i++){
        printf("%d:    %p   0x%lx\n", j, i, *i);
        j++;
    }
}

int main(){
    unsigned long p = 0x1;
    foo(&p);
    back:
    printf("\n  p:    %p \n", &p);
    printf("  back: %p \n", &&back);
    return 0;
}
```

When executing it prints this:

```
Line: Address          Value 
1:    0x7fffffffdd68   0x3
2:    0x7fffffffdd70   0x7fffffffdd70
3:    0x7fffffffdd78   0x1ac4447e35ba0000
4:    0x7fffffffdd80   0x7fffffffdda0
5:    0x7fffffffdd88   0x5555555547b0
6:    0x7fffffffdd90   0x1

  p:    0x7fffffffdd90 
  back: 0x5555555547b0
```

Line really means in which order it stored in the stack. 
Line 1 are the `first_out_of_stack` variable's data, the 4th line is from my understanding the Previous stack base pointer (EBP), line 5 is the return address from foo and line 6 is from my understanding the data from the variable `p`.

Are my assumptions correct and what does line 2 and 3 mean?

Comment: Is this the full code? Where are variables `stop` and `r` declared?

Comment: while it might be ok to use this kind of program to get a glimpse at what's happening under the hood, please be aware that this program exhibits Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @bolov What kind of Undefined Behavior?

Comment: You're dereferencing pointers out of the scope of the object they point to and also doing pointer arithmetic that goes beyond one past the last element in the array being pointed to.  Each of these result in undefined behavior.

Comment: what do you think would happen if `p` were optimized into a register?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons This project is *obviously* an attempt to investigate platform specific behaviour. Of course it's not defined by the C language, that's the point. Your comment should be more like bolov's.

Comment: @bruceg well it can't be because its address is taken.

Comment: You could look at the assembly code to see exactly what's going on. I suspect 0x7fffffffdd70 is the variable `i` and 0x1ac4447e35ba0000 is a [stack canary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Stack_canaries).

Comment: @immibis The OP asked about what undefined behavior bolov was referring to, so I gave a couple examples.